# Azure storage pricing : Charged for 30 gb?

Tags: azure, storage

Hy ppl , I dont understand how azure storage is charged for around 34gb in my subscription. We havent used that much storage space.

I heard there is a quest tool for azure storage explorer.How useful is that ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Virtual Machines? If that's the case, you have to know that persisted disks are stored as page blobs in your storage account, and you're charged for that. The [pricing details](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#virtual-machines) page explains why:

> Compute hours do not include any Windows Azure Storage costs
>   associated with the image running in Windows Azure Virtual Machines.
>   These costs are billed separately. For a full description of how
>   compute hours are calculated, please refer to the Cloud Services
>   section.

If you want to know more details on how much data you've used per storage account/day/location/... I suggest you take a look on the [subscriptions](https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions/) page. After choosing a subscription you can export a detailed CSV file you can analyse.

Comment: I am using virtual machines.So u mean to say some 30 gb is allocated and charged, though we have only few gb used in it ???

Comment: It depends (note that your system disk containing the OS also counts). Your best bet would be to use a tool like the Azure Storage Explorer to take a look at the container containing the VHDs. You'll be able to see the size of each VHD.

Comment: Hi Sandrino, What is that i dont understand is , my three storage blobs contains approx 3,1,11 units of usage. But the bill shows 66gb per month.It should have shown like 66 gb divided by 3 days rite ???